# "Cannot convert null to "int" because it is a non-nullable value type"

Tags: c#

```
 void GetMessages()
    {
        var _HttpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        string Response = HttpRequest.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getLastActivity?user_id=" + tbID.Text + "&access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN + "&v=5.68").ToString();
        dynamic JSON = JObject.Parse(Response);
        int Activity = JSON.online; /* 0 - offline, 1 - online */
    }
```

Вызов метода должен отправить такой ответ:

```
{"response":{"online":0,"time":1503753794}}
```

Где независимо от параметров я получаю ошибку, указывающая на строку:

```
int Activity = JSON.online;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `JSON.response.online`?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, можешь написать не в комментарии, я поставлю галочку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается `JObject`, у которого есть свойство `response`, а уж в нём содержится `JObject` со свойством `online`.

При обращении к `JSON.online` `JObject` «на лету» создаёт пустое свойство со значением `null`, которое невозможно превратить в `int`.

Используйте

```
JSON.response.online
```